# Meaning of "East Indian cottons"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is the sentence:

> Tariffs prohibiting the import of East Indian cottons, imposed by the
>   Parliament to stimulate the sale of woollen goods, have instead served
>   to spur the manufacture of domestic cotton goods.

I know the lexical meaning of "East Indian", but I am not sure if the author is referring to East Asian countries or East Indies.

You will find more information [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Pcf1nrvUwD0C&pg=PA48&lpg=PA48&dq=%22East%20Indian%20cottons,%20imposed%22&source=bl&ots=IPeL5jugtX&sig=97hIYmGvlnZFeOWDsTX3b9bi-Sk&hl=hi&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwji2f7L7MrWAhUENI8KHcuhATcQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=%22East%20Indian%20cottons%2C%20imposed%22&f=false).

Comment: A short wikipedia search = https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_Indies

Comment: I don't think "East Indian" would ever mean "East Asian".  Maybe it could mean "from the east of the country called India", but context should make that clear.

Comment: The usage is probably related to the [British East India Company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_India_Company) given the historical context. However, your question is about proper name usage in a historical context, not about learning English.

Comment: As a side note, what is a little odd is the sudden switch to present perfect in the midst of a passage where all of the other verbs are in simple past. (responded, were made, was such, *have served*, took place).

Answer (score 2):

Unless otherwise indicated in the context you can assume the author refers to the region known as the "East Indies"

> The East Indies or Indies are the lands of South and Southeast Asia. In a more restricted sense, the Indies can be used to refer to the islands of Southeast Asia, especially the Malay Archipelago. [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_Indies)

If the author means "from Eastern India" then that's what they should say.

Of course an author might not know the convention, so you can never *really* be sure. In most cases you can verify the geography from other contextual clues, such as place names or unique cultural references.

Comment: "East India"  is a widely used term in the textile industry.  See *Dictionary of Textiles.* Louis Harmuth. New York 1915.